# Fixing 'Your Ruby version is 2.4.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1' error with rbenv and rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I know there are many many questions about this with various ruby versions. I believe I have exhausted all of the normal fixes (which usually work).

This is an application that has been working, in the same environment that I have now for several months (and years before that for other people). It has previously worked with both ruby 2.4.4 and ruby 2.5.1 (switching with rbenv).

I want ruby 2.5.1 and bundler is complaining that my ruby version is 2.4.4

```
$ bundle exec rspec
Your Ruby version is 2.4.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

$ rbenv exec bundle exec rspec
Your Ruby version is 2.4.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1
```

*NOTE: `rspec` is the example but it is happening for any command prepended with `bundle exec`*

I have checked all the places that I know about, and all the places that the internet has suggested I should look, and cannot find what is setting ruby to 2.4.4 (see details below).

So the real question is - where is the next place to look for a mis-configured file for either `rbenv` or `bundler` or both?

All of these things give me the correct ruby version

The basics:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

$ which ruby
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims/ruby

$ rbenv which ruby
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.16.3

$ which bundle
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims/bundle

$ rbenv which bundle
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle

$ bundle platform --ruby
ruby 2.5.1p57

$ rbenv version
2.5.1 (set by /path/to/app/.ruby-version)

$ rbenv local
2.5.1

$ rbenv global
2.5.1

$ head Gemfile -n 6
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |name| "https://github.com/#{name}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'

$ tail Gemfile.lock -n 5
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.3
```

**bundle env**

````
$ bundle env

## Environment

```
Bundler       1.16.3
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/etc
RubyGems      2.7.6
  Gem Home    /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  Gem Path    /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  User Path   /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  Bin Dir     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
Tools
  Git         1.9.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.1-37-g1c772d5

  chruby      not installed
```

## Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2018-07-17
Git SHA           12e73cab7
Released Version  true
```

... (snip)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.3
````

**gem env**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin
```

**cat**

```
$ cat /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundler
#!/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'bundler' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

if Gem.respond_to?(:activate_bin_path)
load Gem.activate_bin_path('bundler', 'bundler', version)
else
gem "bundler", version
load Gem.bin_path("bundler", "bundler", version)
end
```

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the `bundler` gem? `gem install bundler`

Comment: Yes, I'll enumerate the things I've tried later today. In short, I have tried completely uninstalling bundler, and reinstalling it, and running rbenv rehash (even though you aren't supposed to need that anymore). I did a gem pristine as well.
This may have to do with rails 4/5 binstubs and bundler binstubs not liking each other.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the command `ruby -v` from inside the project dir? Also if you installed a new Ruby version, you should update your bundler as well. `gem install bundler` or `gem update bundler` will do this for you.

Comment: All of the commands in the question are done from the project directory. Both `gem install` and `gem update` have been tried. As well as a `gem uninstall bundler` then a fresh `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game, but perhaps this will prove helpful to somebody:

TLDR; you may have a conflicting version manager.

More background information:

I use thoughtbot's laptop script to manage the software I install on my computer. I hadn't updated in quite a long. I finally updated, but found after the update that my applications were no longer working. After quite a bit of time spent following the usual suggestions for this issue I finally paid more attention to the actual errors I was receiving and noticed a reference to `asdf`. It turns out `asdf` is a general language version manager, and the scripts had started using it some time ago. I had never heard of it before that. I read a bit of the documentation, it sounded pretty good, so I removed `rbenv`, did the basic setup, and voila, my applications are working again! This is probably also relevant if one has other ruby version managers.

The long story short, having multiple version managers is probably a bad idea, which could result in all kinds of problems running applications.